# Can I be more specific in passing in a 2-dimensional array where one dimension is a string but the other a "generic"

Tags: java, generics, types

My function prototype:

```
private String buildParamaters(Object[][] arguments)
```

This method builds up an URL.

An example value of **arguments** might be:

```
List<String> items = ...
new Object[][] {{"key1", 25}, 
                {"key2", "a string"},
                {"key3", items}}
```

So, the first dimension is always a String but the second dimension could be a range of types.

Instead of Object[][] how can I define this argument so that the first dimension is a String? And bonus question: is there any practical alternative to defining the second dimension as a generic type?

Comment: Could you not use a Map (like HashMap) instead of a 2 dimensional array? since arrays and generics do not mix well.

Comment: If these are key-value pairs for parameters, a humble suggestion would be to wrap your own Pair<String, Object> or use Map's Entry type and then use this type for your array. But I geuss that's not as cool as you were hoping!

Comment: Or indeed GJ13's suggestion of a hashmap, of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace an array of arrays with an array of custom objects, like this:

```
public class KeyedItem {
     private final String key;
     private final Object value;
     public KeyedItem(String key, Object value) {
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
     }
}
...
private String buildParamaters(KeyedItem[] arguments) {
    ...
}
...
KeyedItem[] arguments = new KeyedItem[] {
    new KeyedItem("key1", 25)
,   new KeyedItem("key2", "a string")
,   new KeyedItem("key3", items)
};
```

Comment: this is only a little more verbose than the "Object[][]" approach but self-documents the key/value pairs.

Comment: Might there be a way of defining KeyItems[] such that items could be embedded in the {} without requiring a "new KeyEdItem()" for each pair?

Comment: @Carl Unfortunately, no, but you can define a function that converts an array of arrays of objects to an array of `KeyedItem` objects. You could also rename the class to use a shorter name if it's private to another class and is used only for initialization.

Comment: I suppose buildParameters() already converts from Object[][] so I could continue with that approach or rename your class to KV (key/value). Thanks for your answer and follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for this? Example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> items = new HashMap<String, Object>();
items.put("key1", 25);
```

Comment: the list of arguments I'm using are only listed together to pass to buildParameter(). It looks like overkill to declare a variable and make multiple put() calls and then pass the variable to the function never to use that structure again. Also... If I want a very strict URL constructed with the keys in a specific red then this isn't possible with a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a map between strings and objects, therefore something like:

```
Map<String, Object>
```

Or, instead of `Object`, you may want to place a type parameter if this is happening in a type-parameterized method or class.

Comment: In Java the only type hat can be used is Object to satisfy the example vales given.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to build a URL, you could also use a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s collections, which allows you to have several values for one key, as can happen with query parameters:

```
Multimap<String, Object> params = HashMultimap.create();
params.put("key1", "value1");
params.put("key2", 2);
params.put("key2", 3);
```

Comment: One downside: as keys are not returned in a reliable order it's possible that different URLs could be built for the same app.

Comment: @Carl unless you use one of the immutable implementations, which preserves insertion order (for both keys and values).